# Instantiate global type from namespace having type with the same name

Tags: typescript

I have a `class A` declared globally:

```
class A { }
```

And I have `namespace N`, which together with other types have `class A` as well:

```
namespace N {
    class A { }
    // other declarations
}
```

How could I instantiate global `class A` inside of `namespace N` ?

```
namespace N {
    export class B {
        static getA(): A {   // here 
            return new A();  // and here I want to refer global A, not N.A
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By forced typing hack. In JavaScript you can access variables at global level by global variable which is in web browser `window` and in node.js `global`. For web browser it is easy. You can choose syntax what you prefer.

```
return new (<any>window).A()
```

or

```
return new (window as any).A()
```

Little bit more complicated it is when your app is running in node.js or other non-browser platforms which have another global variable. I don't know about more pretty solution which will hack getting global variable (because global is keyword in TypeScript).

```
return new (eval("global")).A()
```